# how to update a colunm in asp.net(better disscription later)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

first this is homework, but all but this part works like it needs to

second the specification:The Add and Edit pages should not include the Date Added field that’s displayed by the Details page. That field should only be set only by code when the user first adds a contact.

third the problem I can't get my code to update Time.

the code to start with:

```
    <a class="form-group">
        @{

            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            int result = DateTime.Compare(dt, Model.Time);
            
            if (result < 0) {  }
            if (result == 0) { Model.Time = DateTime.Now;}
         }
    </a>
```

I know this code does not update it but trying to open the database and use sql to update it did not work(it said that Database did not exist, not the database the word Database had no context)

thanks in advance for any help

if i am missing something comment and i will put an edit under this line

Answer (score 0):

how i ended up doing it

```
    <a class="form-group">
        @{

            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            int result = DateTime.Compare(dt, Model.Time);
            DateTime dt2 = Model.Time;
            if (result < 0)
            {

                result = DateTime.Compare(dt2, Model.Time);
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Time" value="@dt2" />
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error injudgement");
                }

            }
            if (result == 0)
            {

                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Time" value="@DateTime.Now" />

            }


        }
    </a>
```